# Does neo4j support UNIX OS (AIX, HP-US, Solaris, SunOS)?

Tags: unix, neo4j, installation

How does each edition (community, enterprise) support UNIX?

I need general information on UNIX, including SunOS, Solaris, HP-UX, and AIX.

If all versions of Unix are supported, can it also run with the downloaded official versions of Linux from the homepage? Or do I need to get a Unix-only package through separate technical support?

Comment: As reference: [neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/linux/](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/linux/)

Answer (score 1):

The [Installation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/) chapter of the neo4j Operations Manual should be helpful, especially the [Linux installation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/linux/) section; and the [System requirements](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/requirements/) section documents the supported versions of Linux.

You just install the desired Linux distribution from its official site.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out more about the different Linux distributions supported and how to download them from: [linux installation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.5/installation/linux/)

I hope this helps.